# Force browser to load using Ruby with Watir and Webdriver

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

When I run the following code, I get a timeout waiting for the element:

```
require 'watir'
require 'webdrivers'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://watir.com/examples/forms_with_input_elements.html"
browser.text_field(:id, "new_user_username").set("test")
```

> /home/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/watir-6.9.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:618:in
>   `raise_disabled': element present and enabled, but timed out after 30
>   seconds, waiting for # < Watir::TextField: located: true;
>   {:id=>"new_user_username", :tag_name=>"input"}> to not be disabled
>   (Watir::Exception::ObjectDisabledException)

The chrome window starts and doesn't seem to load. I can force it to load by resizing the window after it starts and everything works fine, but I should not have to take any manual steps. Is there an automated way to force the browser to load?

Comment: That's odd; I just verified it is working for me. Can you run it with `Selenium::WebDrivers.logger.level = :info` and put the results into a gist? It shouldn't find the element and then complain about it being disabled if the page hasn't loaded. I want to see what wire calls it is making for that to happen. Actually tack on `Watir.logger.level = :debug` as well.

Comment: I added the trace and let it run for a second before resizing the window. https://gist.github.com/ryanesch/9b589035a1ac0abbd50794dad7219d21

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, it's an interactable error. Those can't be easily figured out ahead of time. For some reason chromedriver doesn't think it can move the element to where it can enter text.

You can either try `browser.window.maximize`, or `browser.window.move_to(x,y)` or you can use Alex's excellent [watir-scroll.gem](https://github.com/p0deje/watir-scroll/) to position the element inside the viewport where chromedriver can use it.

Comment: Thanks! move did not seem to work but maximize does. I'll try out watir-scroll.gem later.